# Can't resize img logo in nav-bar while using display: flex;

Tags: html, css, sass

So, I'm creating a basic nav-bar with a  that is a logo and a  with lists in it. However, my logo image is disproportionally huge compared to the site. So I tried resizing it

```
#logo {
    width: 13.3rem;
    height: auto;
  }
```

which worked up until I added

```
#logo {
    width: 13.3rem;
    height: auto;
    flex: 2;
  }
```

flex works regularly, but my image is now blown out of proportion, seemingly negating the width and height that I set.

I'm new to programming, so if anyone could help me out/explain flex more to me, that would be much appreciated.

Also, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IjyqauKumE&t) is the video that I am following, but instead of using a  as the logo, I'm using an actual image. The problem occurs when he adds the flex value at 21:15.

Answer (score 0):

just add height to your logo

```
#logo {
    width: 13.3rem;
    height: ?;
}
```

Comment: I gave it a height but now my logo is stretched. I tried giving it a max-width but that just made the flex not work.